# I can't add a class to tag although it say ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code is:

```
<li>
   <a href="san-pham/thoi-trang-nam">Thời trang nam <span class="category-widget-btn"></span></a>
   <ul style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="san-pham/ao-nam" class="cat_lv2">Áo nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/ao-khoac" class="cat_lv2">Áo khoác</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/quan-nam" class="cat_lv2">Quần nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/giay-dep-nam" class="cat_lv2">Giày dép nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/ao-vest-plazer" class="cat_lv2">Áo vest, plazer</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/do-lot-va-ngu" class="cat_lv2">Đồ lót và ngủ</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/do-the-thao" class="cat_lv2">Đồ thể thao</a></li>
      <li><a href="san-pham/phu-kien" class="cat_lv2">Phụ kiện</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

and my jQuery to try add `class="open"` to the first `<li>` tag:

```
$('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
    $(this).parents().eq(3).addClass('open');
});
```

I don't see anything change when I click on one of the `class="cat_lv2"` links.

So, I tested it by code:

```
$('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
       if( $(this).parents().eq(3).addClass('open')) {
           alert('ok');
       }
    });
```

and I receive a popup that says "ok".

Why won't my code work?

Comment: Ok you want to add class="open" , but to which element?

Comment: As an aside: You should tag this with 'jquery' instead of 'javascript'.

Comment: I want to add this claas to first tag <li>

Comment: Your `if` isn't actually checking if the class was added or not.  `.addClass()` will just return the jQuery object it was called on.  Regardless of whether there are any elements in it or not, it'll always be `true`.

Comment: Works here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbbRjO once I added `preventDefault()` to keep the click from actually trying to load the `href` page.

Comment: But when I added preventDefault(), i can't load my page with this menu?

Comment: @Thunder.Sivler: He just added `preventDefault` to make his example (which doesn't have the code for the menu).

Comment: If I didn't add preventDefault, my code would been worked?

Comment: Code of  Paul Roub is work. But, i can't load my page with it.

Comment: @Thunder.Sivler: He was just trying to make an *example*.  Your code is different.

Comment: *I want to add this claas to first tag <li>* Do you want it added to the `li` tag of whichever link you click or do you want it added to the first `li` tag in the list, regardless of which link you click on?

Comment: ca you be more specific , to which element  you want to add class, in OP you gave `li >ul > li ,li,li....`. so definitely there are 2 `ul`'s in your code.  so give us  clarity to help you

Comment: @BSMP, I want to click class class="cat_lv2", then add a class="open" to lasted parent li from a > li > ul > li (here, I want to add class)

Answer (score 1):

You are going up too many parents.  You want `.eq(2)`, not `.eq(3)`.

```
$('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
    $(this).parents().eq(2).addClass('open');
});
```

`.eq()` is 0-indexed, so you need to use `2` to get the 3rd element.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  How do you know the class isn't being added?

Comment: It's actually `.eq(1)` as the `<li class "cat_lv2">` only have the `<ul>` and the outer `<li>` as ancestors per the example HTML.

Comment: @Bytor: Guess I wasn't sure which element he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have misunderstood how the `.parents()` function in jQuery works.

The `.parents()` function returns the list of **ancestors** of the DOM object it is acting on. It looks like you were thinking that it gets the list of all the DOM objects (HTML tags) which appeared before it in the HTML document.

So in your code, `$('.cat_lv2')` is that bunch of `<li>` tags inside the `<ul style="display: block;">` tag. So their parents are that `<ul>` and that outer, classless `<li>` tag. Neither the `<a>` tag nor the `<span>` tag are ancestors of that set of `<li class="cat_lv2">` tags. The `<a>` is a sibling of the `<ul>`.

As a result, your function should be this:

```
$('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('open');
});
```

To add the class "open" to that outer `<li>`.

As @RocketHazmat mentioned in a comment, your `if` in your test is useless because that bit of jQuery is always returning a value which is equivalent to `true`. [As per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> If an element cannot be found at the specified zero-based index, the
>   method constructs a new jQuery object with an empty set and a length
>   property of 0.

So `.eq(3)` returns an empty list, not a null, and `.addClass("open")` returns an object, as @RocketHazmat said, indicating that nothing was acted upon.

Comment: I find a ressult as you say. It's a give me a list of element. I want to add class="open" to li from another tag inside. from a > li > ul > li (here, I want to add calss)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `li` containing the `a` tag that was clicked you only need to get the first parent:

```js
  $('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
  });
```

```css
.open {
    background: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <a href="#">Thời trang nam <span class="category-widget-btn"></span></a>
   <ul style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo khoác</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Quần nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Giày dép nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo vest, plazer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ lót và ngủ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ thể thao</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Phụ kiện</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

But if you want to change the first `li` tag no matter which `a` is clicked you could traverse up to the `ul` tag and find the first child:

```js
$('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
      var ul= $(this).parent().parent();
      ul.find(">:first-child").addClass('open');
    });
```

```css
.open {
    background: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <a href="#">Thời trang nam <span class="category-widget-btn"></span></a>
   <ul style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo khoác</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Quần nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Giày dép nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo vest, plazer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ lót và ngủ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ thể thao</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Phụ kiện</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

**OR**

Just give the first item an ID since you're always just changing the one thing.

```js
    $('.cat_lv2').click(function () {
      $("#firstItem").addClass('open');
    });
```

```css
.open {
    background: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <a href="#">Thời trang nam <span class="category-widget-btn"></span></a>
   <ul style="display: block;">
      <li id="firstItem"><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo khoác</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Quần nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Giày dép nam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Áo vest, plazer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ lót và ngủ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Đồ thể thao</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cat_lv2">Phụ kiện</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok. I'm doing it. Thank you very much.